# Combine two strings with commas in R

Tags: r

I haven't been able to find an answer to this, but I am guessing this is because I am not phrasing my question properly.

I want to combine two strings containing several comma-separated values into one string, alternating the inputs from each original string.

```
x <- '1,2'
y <- 'R,L'

# fictitious function
z <- combineSomehow(x,y) 

z = '1R, 2L'
```

EDIT :  Adding dataframe to better describe my issue. I would like to be able to accomplish the above, but within a `mutate` ideally.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c('1','2','1,1','2','1'),
  y = c('R','L','R,L','L','R'),
  desired_result = c('1R','2L','1R,1L','2L','1R')
)
```

df:

```
    x   y desired_result
1   1   R             1R
2   2   L             2L
3 1,1 R,L          1R,1L
4   2   L             2L
5   1   R             1R
```

**Final Edit/Answer:**  Based on @akrun's comment/response below and after removing the error originally in `df`, this ended up being the `tidyverse` answer:

```
mutate(desired_result = map2(.x=strsplit(x,','),.y=strsplit(y,','),
                                   ~ str_c(.x,.y, collapse=',')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `strsplit` and `paste`

```
combineSomehow <- function(x, y) {
       do.call(paste0, c(strsplit(c(x,y),","), collapse=", "))
   }

combineSomehow(x,y) 
#[1] "1R, 2L"
```

---

Without modifying the function, we can `Vectorize` it to apply on multiple elements

```
df$desired_result2 <-  Vectorize(combineSomehow)(df$x, df$y)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this works great for the provided issue.  However, I am trying to apply this same operation to two columns in a dataframe in a `mutate` and not getting the same results. Based on what I see it's running the combination and placing the entire resulting value in the cell.  I added a little extra to my question, if you have time.

Comment: @TTS you can pass the columns as `combineSomehow(df1$x, df1$y)`

Comment: @TTS If the dataset is `df1 <- data.frame(x = rep(x, 3), y = rep(y, 3)); Vectorize(combineSomehow)(df1$x, df1$y)`

Comment: @TTS The last element is not clear.  How does it differentiate between whether it needs to paste on right or left.  is it based on the value?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again!  (Oops! That last element was a typo- good catch, though.)

Comment: @TTS Or in tidyverse, it can be `df %>% mutate(desired_result2 = map2(strsplit(x, ","), strsplit(y, ","), ~ if(length(.x) == length(.y)) str_c(.x, .y) else str_c(.x[2], .y)))`